# why open call taking two arguments (struct inode *, struct file*)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm implementing a Character Driver. So I'm registering file operations.  When I'm registering `read` function i extracted `minor` number this way

```
     myread(struct file * file, char __user * ubuf, size_t lbuf, loff_t *offset)
     {
         int minor;

         minor = MINOR(file->f_path.dentry->d_inode->f_pos->i_rdev);
         .......
```

This rule will apply to `open` call too.

```
     myopen(struct inode * inode, struct file * file)
```

`struct file` definition have the reference to `struct inode`. So one argument is enough for `open` call.

My questions are:

1. Why `open` have two arguments? (or) why `read` don't have `struct inode *` argument?
2. To extract minor number in `read` call, i used above instruction. To find the definions and header files it took 1hr 30min to me. Is there any easy way to find the definitions of structures?
3. How many ways we can find the reference of `struct inode` through `struct file`  and what is the best way?

Comment: Because the kernel conventions are so. Changing them requires a lot of code rewriting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not use that construction to search for the inode; the file or even directory might have been deleted after the file was opened.

The kernel convention (see chapter 3 of [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/)) is that

1. in your `open` function, you look up your own data from the inode (or allocate your own data), and set the `file->private_data` pointer; and
2. in your `read` function, you then use `file->private_data` to access your own stuff.